Blocks randomly open and close or glare on their own and it's only visible on the monitor
I have faced today a problem with randomly closing and opening different blocks on Ubuntu 22.04. In the 2 videos below I gave an example on Pycharm but it happens in other applications as well. And moreover, this problem is not visible in screencast. I have a Nvidia 4060 video card, and before asking the question I reinstalled the drivers, it didn't help.
Screencast: https://streamable.com/pzd1nf
Video from mobile: https://streamable.com/19875p
